# Download HTML page in webclient with multilingual c#

Tags: c#, html, multilingual

How can i download HTML page with all languages supported in it?

Here is my C# code.

```
using(var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    var str = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.dinamalar.com/news_detail.asp?id=1553568");
}
```

For example, the HTML page I am downloading contains TAMIL words then the downloaded html is unreadable. So what can i do for supporting other languages in downloaded html document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Set Encoding property of web client object.

```
using(var webClient = new WebClient())
{
  webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  var str =   webClient.DownloadString("http://www.dinamalar.com/news_detail.asp?id=1553568");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the encoding of the WebClient by using

```
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.Default; //or whatever enconding works for you
```